# Page is not responsive when it is resized to a small window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap to make my page to be responsive.
If the window is big.It is fine as shown in the first image. 
[image: img_1])
The welcome message and the three blocks are positioned well.

When I make the window small, the text in the Welcome message goes under the blocks. Then the last block's position is shifted down as shown in the second image.
[image: img].

CSS are shown for Welcome message and blocks.

```
.blocks {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 300px; 
}

.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 250px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    /* padding: 25px; */ 
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}


.welcome{
text-align: center;
color: #00ff00;
height: 150px;
width: 50%;
margin: auto;

}
```

My HTML is

```
<div class = "container-fluid  carousel_pos" style="overflow-y: auto">   
  <div class="row"> 
    <div id="awesome-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to ######Tourism</h1>
    <p>Wwer eree ere ae llji er we lkjj ewer  jlkjkj erw jkljer lkjkje werewer wkerkjkl. We reakl lkjle aere ar akljiu are jearear lkljkjare. Jk are lkjklul kljrea elkjare lj. He ioierwer sdfsdf sdfeiuit kare adfkjkjl. Wer kjljser sejrlj ekrjkjsfiu ekrjlkejk.</p>
   </div>

    <div class="blocks">
      <div class="col-sm-4 box1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 box2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 box3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
[image: IMG]

Comment: log out from wordpress then visit the site.Take a look is it happening again or not? Also give image height with % in your css.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud, yes it happens. Also same thing happened at the mobile.

Comment: No issue in the code you have posted: https://jsfiddle.net/o4dmrk4m/

Comment: @batuman give image height in % it will be worked.

Comment: @silviagreen, got issue, please see in the EDIT. Yeah no issue for text. Just the last block has issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a fixed `height` to `.welcome` so when the window is smaller the `.welcome` has a `height` of `150px`. Get rid of `height: 150px;` in `.welcome` and it will work. See the code working https://jsfiddle.net/o4dmrk4m/1/

Comment: See also the @MarcoSantino answer, it will help you to better use bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

in first time you must add class "row" in div with class "blocks". In second time, if you use bootstrap, you can remove width from "box1", "box2" and "box3", because you can substitute "col-sm-4" with "col-xs-4".

This is the example:

HTML:

```
<div class="row blocks">
  <div class="col-xs-4 box1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 box2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 box3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
height: 250px;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
/* padding: 25px; */}
```

Test this solution.

Bye!

Comment: JS fiddle link to support MarcoSantino

Comment: Yes thank you.Your solution makes all blocks are aligned well.

Answer (score 0):

you are re-sizing your width with using `width: 33.333%;` Use either this attribute or bootstrap column. I would prefer to use only bootstrap classes to determine row width sizes.

I would use something like this:

```
<div class="row col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
  <div class="col-sm-4 " style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 " style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 " style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```